# "Symbols Tool failed" error while exporting iPhone application with APP Store Profile

Tags: iphone, ios7

After successful Archive, while exporting the Archive to "Save for App Store Deployment", I got the following error:
"Symbol Tool Failed".

During the Export sequence, I have observed, "Binary and Entitlements" section, has two entries.
1) The app store targetAppName (5 Entitlements). with valid Provisioning Profiles.
2) One of the build files **FTALDeviceDetailsViewController.o** (o Entitlement) with Provisioning Profiles (none)

I bet the second entry here is what is causing the error. Here is the error log:

Any one know how to remove the second entry?

I found another interesting information, regarding this issue:

Unser Archive folder
ActiveLife\ 11-12-14\,\ 3.56\ AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/ActiveLife.app/

I found following 3 files those are generated in response to second Entitlement file:

```
FTALDeviceDetailsViewController.d
FTALDeviceDetailsViewController.dia
FTALDeviceDetailsViewController.o
```

I have manually deleted these 3 files, and now I am able to generate .ipa file.

Now still mystery to me is; why are these files generated and how to fix the root of the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for the issue is, some how `FTALDeviceDetailsViewController.m` file is ended up `Copy Bundle Resources` causing this is be treated as separate target. 
When I delete the file from the Copy Bundle Resource, every thing worked as expected.

Now the mystery questions to me, what are .d .dia generated? This is up for further study.

Comment: Thanks for this, I ran into the same issue with a third-party library. My guess is that .d is the file containing debug symbols whereas .dia is probably a diagnostics helper?

Comment: Life-saver! I was beating my head against the wall with this issue.

Comment: @jessecurry Awesome! Happy to know it helped.

Answer (score 18):

I experienced the same "Symbols Tool Failed" issue yesterday.  With the following more detailed error:

```
Archive upload failed due to the issues listed below.

Unable to validate your application.
The path '/var/folders/c6/wfv094t921j7q1bzhht5wtdnhvjv1/T/XcodeDistPipeline.blK/Packages/XXXXXX.ipa' does not contain a file.
```

[image: Symbols Tool Failed]

[image]

The cause of the problem was that a third party library (*.a file) had accidentally been included in the "Copy Bundle Resources" "Build Phase".  The give-away that this was the problem was that this *.a library appeared in the list of "Binary and Entitlements" screen when submitting the upload:

[image: Extra library in binary and entitlements]

Ultimately the third party source code had been added to our workspace as a "Folder Reference" and someone had checked the 'target membership' for that folder.  This resulted in the the third parties libary folder (which contained the *.a) being included in the "Copy Bundle Resources".  Simply unchecking the 'target membership' box for the folder fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks a ton Oliver, you made my day. Looking to fix this for a long while, finally removing the target for the folder did the trick

Answer (score 5):

Unchecking "Upload your app's symbols to receive symbolicated reports from Apple" option fixes the "Symbol tools failed" error when you Archive the app in Organiser window of Xcode.[image]

Comment: This shouldn't be de solution, it's the same solution than if I have an error on a method, remove this method

Comment: weird, but it worked for me as well .

Answer (score 2):

I faced this too, and trying to find something wrong with the copy bundle resources, as the previous answers, I found a folder being copied, removing it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Basically some framework has been added to Copy Bundle Resources. Remove it to resolve the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Could also be that there is a framework unnecessarily added in 'Embed Frameworks' in Xcode Build Phases

Answer (score 0):

"Symbols Tool Failed" error can also be caused by this.

[image]

Xcode 13.1 - Check BuildTarget -> General -> Frameworks and Libraries.  If something is marked as `Embed And Sign` it may need to be changed to `Do Not Embed`.