# Why does the Xcode Symbols tool fail when submitting an application to the Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-app-store, quicklook

When I submit my application for the Mac App Store I get the following error:

`The symbols tool failed, could not determine the executable path for the item path: "<DVTFilePath:0x2c242c1c0:'/var/folders/6j/ndqvj9rj68938svkmy7_d75c0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~gkLhyf/MyAppQuickLook.qlgenerator'>".`

The error message then invites me to file a bug report at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com.

Is this necessary though?  I've spotted a few things which make me wonder if the problem is mine.

1. There has never been a problem previously. When submitting using older versions of Xcode, I never saw this error.
2. The code for the Quicklook Generator hasn't changed.  There are two warnings in the code - these being about casting to a smaller integer type (which is deliberate, but I include for completeness)
3. The application also contains a Spotlight importer.  This too contains no changed code, and it doesn't seem to be causing any problems.  It also has the same warning about casting.
4. I have a Copy Files build phase for both the QLGenerator (Quicklook) and the MDImporter (Spotlight), with a destination of Wrapper and the appropriate Subpath for both.  Both are set to Code Sign on Copy.
5. Looking in the General tab of the Project, I see that MyAppSpotlight.mdimporter is present, with Embed & Sign.  MyAppQuicklook.qlgenerator is missing.  If I attempt to add it directly here then it ends up the Copy Files phase as a plugin - in either event it doesn't work.
6. I am running Xcode 13.3.1 (13E500a) on an M1 Mac mini.
7. For what it's worth, all the code is written in Objective C - but it passes its tests (i.e. in testing the QLGenerator does what it is supposed to do)

Does this look like something that I can fix (any suggestions on how?) or do I in fact need to follow the invitation to file a bug report?

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882037/symbols-tool-failed-error-while-exporting-iphone-application-with-app-store-pr. Just as a test, try doing the upload without the debugging symbols and see if that succeeds.

Comment: Good shout matt! That worked - but I don't like that solution.  Why should this just have started happening - and what would be the way to reinstate 'correct' functionality.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known Xcode issue and should be fixed in Xcode 13.4:

> Fixed an issue with generating symbols for Quick Look plug-ins during app distribution. (91361932)